# Autolock iphone?

Tags: iphone, ipad, unlock, alarm, clock

I use my iPad and iPhone as an alarm clock every night and keep them plugged into the wall. I want to be able to look over during the night and check the time, but I don't want them to be open and unlocked. Is there a way to require passcode when the home button is pressed, while still keeping apps open and visible? Sort of using the app as a "screen saver".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.
Apple offers no API for that.